# Session gets cleared after adding cors filter in web.xml chrome browser

Tags: java, session, angular, cors, tomcat8

This is my scenario:

I have developed a small application using angular2 which runs on node server. My rest services are deployed in tomcat server.
I used to get

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

error when I do any post request.

I solved this issue by adding

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in web.xml.

Now, the post request works properly, but the issue is, anything stored in the request session is cleared when accessed in the subsequent requests.

For eg. I have one login page on app startup.
When I login, I store the logged in user's id in the request session.
After login, I redirect it to home page where I try to get the logged in user's id by calling one more request service by fetching from session, but it returns null.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

This happens with firefox and chrome browser.

It works fine with Edge and IE browser because they have built in cors support.

This is the code for calling the service:

```
getLoggedInUser(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/EmployeeReferralManagement/rest/login/get-logged-in-employee').toPromise()
   .then(res => res.json() as Employee)
   .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is the snapshot of web service calls:

[image: This is the snapshot of web service calls]

Rest service:

```
@GET
@Path("/get-logged-in-employee")
public Response getLoggedInEmployee() throws Exception {
    try {
        Employee loggedInEmployee = CommonUtils.checkSession(request);
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put("employeeId", loggedInEmployee.getEmployeeId());
        response.put("designation", loggedInEmployee.getDesignation());
        return ResponseUtils.sendResponse(200, response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseUtils.sendResponse(500, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

checkSession Method:

```
public static Employee checkSession(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Employee loggedInEmployee = (Employee) request.getSession().getAttribute("employee");
    if(loggedInEmployee == null)
        throw new Exception("Session Expired");
    return loggedInEmployee;
}
```

This is the snapshot of headers tab:
[image: snapshot of headers tab]

Comment: can you add how you make the request. this is my cors <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>

Comment: looks fine.  can you place the request and response

Comment: @Roninio, sorry, I didn't get you. I have added code for rest service.

Comment: Would like to see the Headers Tab

Comment: I have added the snapshot of headers tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129344/discussion-between-roninio-and-abhay-jain).

Answer (score 0):

this is how i have done it on Tomcat 8.

```
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>   <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>
```